# FrameLayouts used similar to layer-list

Tags: android, android-framelayout, layer-list

So,I have a FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bbtn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/testcontur1" />           
    </FrameLayout>
```

What I don't know is what to put this framelayout in between so that it will "act" similar to a layer-list.The layer-list example would be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <item android:id="@+id/backgr">
            <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/background" />
        </item>

        <item android:id="@+id/contur">
            <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/testcontur1" />
        </item>

</layer-list>
```

So, basically, what I need to do is to somehow get reference in java to the first bitmap.This one:

```
 <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/background" />
```

But I cannot manage to this anyhow so I suppose that the only way to achive this, is by using a frameLayout and inside it an imagebutton (or imageview,whatever) and get reference to it by it's ID.

I doubt it helps anyone, but I will also write I need this.I need the reference to the bitmap / ImageButton in order to be able to something like this:

```
reference.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(Color.RED ,PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
```

Any help or thoughts on this would be great, because I'v been trying to achive that since early in the morning and I can't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a reference to your layer drawable. Then use the

```
public Drawable getDrawable (int index)
```

method to get a reference to particular layer you need.
After that you may proceed as you wish.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#getDrawable(int)

I have not tried this out, but I am quite sure it should work.